# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS freezes during RAID recheck of multiple RAIDs

Tags: 22.04, freeze, raid, mdadm

I run Ubuntu 22.04 on a machine with three software RAIDs of different size and geometry, with two of them (they are called `md5` and `md6`) very large. Disks are shared between these arrays for certain reasons.

Every month, `cron` starts a re-check of the software RAID arrays automatically. Because of the shared disks, only one of the three RAID checks can run at a given time, the other ones are paused automatically. Furthermore, the re-check runs only for six hours each day, though I don't know, how the beginning of that six hour time window is determined.

The file system mounted from `md6` froze, when the re-check was interrupted on `md6` on the second day. All processes and threads with reads and writes to that file system got stuck in "uninterruptible sleep". Force-unmounting or force-disassembling of the array was not possible, either, so I had to re-boot to access my data again. Apart from the effective DOS, no data seems to have been lost.

From the log, I see the following happening: On the first day, the check of all three arrays is initiated at the same time. The smallest array, `md1`, wins the race for who gets checked first, while `md5` and `md6` have to wait. `md1` finishes in less than ten minutes and then `md6` continues until the end of day 1.

On day 2, `md5` (not the already commenced `md6`!) wins the race for who gets checked. After six hours, the check of `md5` is interrupted for the day. `md6`, which apparently got the "run" command a few milliseconds later, starts to run, only to receive the 6-hour-stop still within the same second, in which it started.

After that super-quick start-stop of the check on `md6`, `md6` freezes. The first sign of that in the log is a warning, that an attempt to write to the file system journal has been blocked for more than two minutes:

Here the relevant parts of the log ("M" is the name of the machine):

```
Sep  4 08:23:59 M root: mdcheck start checking /dev/md1
Sep  4 08:23:59 M kernel: [1682166.084604] md: data-check of RAID array md1
Sep  4 08:24:00 M root: mdcheck start checking /dev/md5
Sep  4 08:24:00 M kernel: [1682167.725977] md: delaying data-check of md5 until md1 has finished (they share one or more physical units)
Sep  4 08:24:00 M root: mdcheck start checking /dev/md6
Sep  4 08:24:00 M kernel: [1682167.758063] md: delaying data-check of md6 until md5 has finished (they share one or more physical units)
Sep  4 08:33:23 M kernel: [1682730.686726] md: md1: data-check done.
Sep  4 08:33:23 M kernel: [1682730.697864] md: data-check of RAID array md6
Sep  4 08:33:23 M kernel: [1682730.697864] md: delaying data-check of md5 until md6 has finished (they share one or more physical units)
Sep  4 08:34:01 M root: mdcheck finished checking /dev/md1
Sep  4 14:24:02 M root: pause checking /dev/md5 at 0 
Sep  4 14:24:03 M kernel: [1703770.476375] md: md6: data-check interrupted.
Sep  4 14:24:03 M root: pause checking /dev/md6 at 5702160936
Sep  4 14:24:03 M systemd[1]: mdcheck_start.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep  4 14:24:03 M systemd[1]: mdcheck_start.service: Consumed 1.957s CPU time.
Sep  4 20:03:05 M systemd[1]: mdmonitor-oneshot.service: Deactivated successfully.

Sep  5 07:02:14 M root: mdcheck continue checking /dev/md5 from 0 
Sep  5 07:02:14 M kernel: [1763663.944043] md: data-check of RAID array md5
Sep  5 07:02:14 M root: mdcheck continue checking /dev/md6 from 5702160936
Sep  5 07:02:14 M kernel: [1763663.980271] md: delaying data-check of md6 until md5 has finished (they share one or more physical units)
Sep  5 13:02:26 M kernel: [1785276.510597] md: md5: data-check interrupted.
Sep  5 13:02:27 M kernel: [1785276.786479] md: data-check of RAID array md6
Sep  5 13:02:27 M root: pause checking /dev/md5 at 5824508144
Sep  5 13:02:27 M kernel: [1785276.795438] md: md6: data-check interrupted.
Sep  5 13:05:31 M kernel: [1785461.181277] INFO: task jbd2/md6-8:2495 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Sep  5 13:05:31 M kernel: [1785461.181441] task:jbd2/md6-8      state:D stack:    0 pid: 2495 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
Sep  5 13:05:31 M kernel: [1785461.181742]  md_write_start.part.0+0x174/0x220
Sep  5 13:05:31 M kernel: [1785461.181753]  md_write_start+0x14/0x30
Sep  5 13:05:31 M kernel: [1785461.181781]  md_handle_request+0x12d/0x1b0
Sep  5 13:05:31 M kernel: [1785461.181792]  md_submit_bio+0x71/0xc0
Sep  5 14:44:14 M systemd[1]: mdmonitor-oneshot.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Because `/` and `/home` file systems are on unaffected RAIDs, I could still log on after that freeze of `md6`. `cat /proc/mdstat` gave the following information:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid10]
md5 : active raid5 sdd4[1] sdk4[2] sdh4[0] sdl4[4]
      11415389184 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/29 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdd3[0] sdk3[1] sdh3[3] sdl3[2]
      100596736 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md6 : active raid6 sdd2[10] sdk2[9] sdh2[11] sdl2[8] sdg[5] sdf[4] sdb[1] sdc[2] sdi[6] sde[3] sdj[7] sda[0]
      117186867200 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [12/12] [UUUUUUUUUUUU]
      [====>................]  check = 24.3% (2851080676/11718686720) finish=95845361544.0min speed=0K/sec
      bitmap: 0/88 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Please note, that `/proc/mdstat` seems to return the position of the re-check in 1 kB blocks with 2851080676 equal to 5702161352 sectors, which is just 416 sectors (less than one chunk!) away from the 5702160936 logged in `syslog` as the position reached the day before. Therefore I assume a deadlock in the started and then immediately stopped again recheck.

My mitigation so far has been to disable the automatic MD RAID re-check

Answer (score 1):

You might be hitting this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.11/+bug/1942935. It's an upstream kernel bug with patches to fix it coming in linux v5.19.

From [comment 10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.11/+bug/1942935/comments/10), you can try this workaround (switch `md1` to `md5`/`md6`/etc. first):

```
echo active | sudo tee /sys/block/md1/md/array_state
```